# Growl for Windows - multiple monitors

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, growl

For GFW with a Win7 on two monitors, is there a way to choose the display where the notifications appear? Don't want to use extra apps like DisplayFusion to force Growl becz it sucks the CPU as a side effect. All suggestions are welcome as long as they are simple and effective.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can choose the display in the display tab of growl by clicking the icon in the top right of the Displays option (There should be an image with two displays).